# when use protocol not for a delegate in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

A protocol is a list of method statement , anyone who conforms to it must or may implement it .

In most cases,a delegate's implementation relies on protocol,such as below:

```
@protocol VSActivateCouponDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)activateCouponSuccessWithActivateType:(ActivateType)type;
@end
```

My question is protocol's usage scenarios except implementing Delegate ?

Answer (score 1):

For example, any interface that you want to keep generic in terms of not knowing the exact class that will be providing a specific role in some relationship. Delegate is one example of that but any relationship between two classes could use the same approach to abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `NSCopying`, `NSCoding` etc. These are also protocols, but they are not used as delegates.

Let's look at `NSCopying` for example. If a class conforms to `NSCopying`, you know that you can call `copy` on any of its instances (and... copy it ), without even looking at the specific class, you can even pass instances as `id<NSCopying>` - this makes things more decoupled. For instance `NSDictionary` only accepts key values that are `id<NSCopying>`.

To summarize, protocols let you declare behavior without coupling it to a specific class. It doesn't always have to be delegates.

Comment: tks, I get it .  your example really inspires me

Answer (score 0):

an example would be:

say you have an array of arbitrary objects of arbitrary types. now you want to make sure that all the objects at least have a certain function you can call on all of them to make them do something, then you can make all those objects conform to a protocol that has that method, thus making sure all the objects in that array have that certain functionality.

pseudo code of what that may look like:

```
@protocol MyProtocol {
   - (void) doSomething;
}

//used somewhere
for(MyProtocol object in arrayOfUnknownObjects)
  [object doSomething]; //dont know what object's type is but we know it has [doSomething] method
```